# javascript onclick function not working

Tags: php, javascript

So I adapted this code from another function that does work and is used on the same page. I don't know if that could do anything to it, so I thought I'd mention that, and also that both have id="replace" in them, which I don't know if it could interfere.

Anyway, the code to call the function is this:

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($LIKE) != 0)

{

  echo "
        <td id=\"replace\" style=\"text-align:left\">".$like." Likes -- <a style=\"color:#234904\" onmouseover=\"this.style.color='#6666CC'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.color='#234904'\" id=\"" . $POST->id . "\" onclick=\"likePost(this.id)\" name=\"like\">Like This Post</td>
        ";
}
```

the javascript function is defined as this:

```
var xmlHttp;

function likePost(x)
{ 
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
 {
 alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
 return;
 }

var pid = document.getElementById(x).id;
var url="forum-like.php";
url+="?pid="+pid;
url+="&sid="+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

when I click on what should call the function, nothing happens. If I execute the script using the php page called in the js function, that works fine though... I don't know if I missed anything or anything is wrong though... I also know that the $POST->id part does call the right id... hope this is enough info, otherwise let me know and I'll edit in more :D Thanks for any help!

Comment: Open up Firefox + Firebug. Open the NET tab and look at your request/response.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pid = document.getElementById(x).id
```

You're already passing the `id` so just use

```
var pid = id;
```

If you're still having issues then use firebug or your browser's developer tools to get the actual javascript error.

Comment: I think it needs that though, because the javascript function is called in a separate document that is called from the header of the page where it's called? Not sure... also, I've just found that it does seem to register the function, but I need to refresh the page for it to update...

Comment: Elizabeth, if you can't change the js function then just change your php so that it doesn't pass (this.id), but instead just (this).

Comment: !! That worked! Except it seems to be interfering/mixing itself up with the other javascript function using id=replace... that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing this.id to the function, but then trying to use that (x) to then look up the id again as if that were a DOM object.

If you leave the php code as is, you can just change your javascript method to say:

```
url+="?pid="+x;
```

And you can get rid of: (since you are already passing the id and don't need to retrieve it)

```
var pid = document.getElementById(x).id;
```

Hope that works for you!